# jquery - drag & drop from container with overflow set

Tags: jquery, overflow, draggable

I have a conundrum. I had an issue with dragging from a container with `overflow:scroll` set as a style. The dragged element would drop ok in the desired position, but as you were dragging it, it would disappear behind elements until you dropped it.

I found a solution to this using `appendTo:'body'` applied to the draggable settings. All was good....

...until I tested in IE6/7, where I encountered another known issue - of the contents of the container spilling out. The fix this time was to set `position:relative` to the container. This fixed that issue, but now elements being dragged fall behind other elements again.

It seems you cannot have both fixes running concurrently. Or can they? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide some code? (and accept more answers)...

Comment: I've actually solved the riddle thanks. The container also had a z-index applied to it that was causing the issue. It was completely unnecessary so I removed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Panic over. The container also had a z-index applied to it that was causing the issue. It was completely unnecessary so I removed it :)